# Any alternative for waitForPageToLoad

Tags: python, selenium-rc

I am developing automated test cases for my app using selenium RC in python 2.7. When I am using wait_for_time_to_load(time) is throwing error as the timeout is variable in my app. Can anyone suggest me any other alternative for the function "wait_for_page_to_load" which does not take time as a parameter.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to @rs79's code

```
    int iteration = 0;
    //checks the presence of element till a given no of iterations(say 20) to avoid infinite loop
    while(!(selenium.isElementPresent("yourelement")) && iteration < 20){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        iteration++;
    }
```

again this is in java, hopefully you can apply same logic in python.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the absence of an expected element and keep waiting till it appears.

```
while (!(selenium.isElementPresent("your_element_identifier")==true)) {
            selenium.setSpeed("10");
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
```

Evidently, the code above is in Java, but applying the same login in Python should be trivial.